# Error creating a session from desired capabilities

Tags: selenium, appium, webdriver-io

When I run my `wdio` test I get the error:

> `Unable to create session from Desired Capabilities.`

Any recommendation on this?

I have the `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` running. Also I'm running the `Appium`

wdio version = **v4.14.4**

The entire Error:

```
ERROR: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "app": "\u002fhome\u002fAD\full_path.apk",
    "rotatable": true,
    "allowTestPackages": true,
    "appiumVersion": "1.13.0",
    "handlesAlerts": true,
    "deviceName": "ANE-LX2J",
    "requestOrigins": {
      "url": "http:\u002f\u002fwebdriver.io",
      "version": "4.14.4",
      "name": "webdriverio"
    },
    "autoLaunch": true,
    "platformVersion": "8.0.0",
    "locationContextEnabled": true,
    "name": "Test Breadwallet on android real devices",
    "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "browserName": "",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "maxInstances": 1,
    "platformName": "android"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "",
        "platformName": "android"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

More info:

> Build info: version: `3.141.59`
>
> revision: `e82be7d358`
>
> System info: host: `jpdla00159.ad.sbibits.com`
>
> ip: `10.128.0.234`
>
> os.name: `Linux`, os.arch: `amd64`, os.version: `3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64`,
>
> **java.version:`1.8.0_19`**
>
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Capabilities in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
capabilities: {
        device: {
            protocol: "http",
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 4444,
            desiredCapabilities: {
                name: "Android test on my app",
                maxInstances: 1,
                appiumVersion: "1.13.0",
                platformName: "android",
                platformVersion:  "8.0.0",
                automationName: "UiAutomator2",
                browserName: "",
                deviceName:  "ANE-LX2J",
                app:  "/home/AD/xx/full_path.apk",
                autoLaunch: true,
                allowTestPackages: true
            }
        }
    },
_
```

Comment: My capabilities
```
capabilities: {
     device: {
         protocol: "http",
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 4444,
          desiredCapabilities: {
           name: "My app",
           maxInstances: 1,
           appiumVersion: "1.13.0",
           platformName: "android",
           platformVersion:  "8.0.0",
           automationName: "UiAutomator2",
           browserName: "",
           deviceName:  "ANE-LX2J",
           app:  "/full_path.apk",
            autoLaunch: true,
            allowTestPackages: true
}
```

Comment: can you share your appium server logs? That should have some more verbose output to debug this issue